# How to visualize multiple graphs with different input files in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3's Zoomable Icicle layout (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873) to visualize different folder hierarchies on the same screen. Each folder's data is contained in a separate json file.

Using the example Zoomable Icicle layout how can I reuse the code and pass through the different json files to visualize each hierarchy on the same screen and assign them to separate specific html elements?

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest, but certainly not the most elegant, way would be to consume the info from all json files upfront, making sure to combine them hierarchically in the format expected by the layout. Once that is all tucked into a json variable, it is business as usual. But, is this an option?

Comment: Hi @FernOfTheAndes, thanks for your comment, but the graphs / folders need to remain separate...not sure how to address this?

Comment: Put the code in the example in a function and call it several times with the different JSON URLs.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, a little while after I posted this question I  figured it out and did that - working well. If you would like to post that as answer I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, this should be quite simple. All you should need to do in this particular case is wrap the code in the example with a function and call it several times, passing the URL to get data from as a parameter.